# Compare Products use multiple properties

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an Excelsheet and want to compare the products by multiple values. My Excel looks like this:

+-----------+--------+------+-------+---------+-------+
|   Name| kcal   | Fat  | Carbs | Protein | €/kg  |
+-----------+--------+------+-------+---------+-------+
| Product A | 383,00 | 5,90 |  6,50 |   76,00 | 21,98 |
| Product B | 359,00 | 0,70 |  3,20 |   85,00 | 24,90 |
| Product C | 380,90 | 5,86 |  8,79 |   73,25 | 32,17 |
| Product D | 390,00 | 5,50 |  5,30 |   80,00 | 18,96 |
+-----------+--------+------+-------+---------+-------+

I would like to find the "best" product by the following criteria:

1. lowest kcal
2. lowest Fat
3. lowest Carbs
4. highest Protein
5. lowest €/kg

Is there a way to do this with excel/google docs?

Maybe a little add-on. The highest priority is €/kg, after that Protein and the other three have the same importance.

Comment: So in this case, what would be the "best"? ProductB I recon?

Comment: Yes, in this example B would be the best. While the price is not the lowest the high Protein and low Fat make up for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit vague what would be considered the "best", however you could consider adding all these amounts together (subtract the protein) would give you a matrix in which you can get the minimum.

Try:

```
=INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(MIN(INDEX(B2:B5+C2:C5+D2:D5-E2:E5+F2:F5,)),INDEX(B2:B5+C2:C5+D2:D5-E2:E5+F2:F5,),0))
```

Add a multiplication, e.g.: `*1.05` to any of the columns if you consider them to be of more importance.

Comment: Thanks this works. But I have a question what does the INDEX(...F5,) do? Doesn't it need at least a row parameter?

Comment: The `INDEX(<array>,)` is there to mimic the otherwise obligatory `CSE` entering. It will return the array of the calculations made. Notice the comma at the end before the double closing brackets? The single comma represents `,1`. It's the default value for both the `row` and `column` index withing `INDEX`. @E-Nuff