# Excel AGGREGATE Function: #VALUE error when applying boolean array multiplication

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For this example I'm starting with this table:

[image: Example table to illustrate the issue]

[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBcYv.png)

Now I want to calculate the average for each row relating to its group identifier. For that, the code I have in Column AvgValueOfGroup is

`=AGGREGATE(1,6,([@Group]=[Group])*[Value])`

This throws a `#VALUE` error for me.

The last step of the calculation is looking normal:

`=AGGREGATE(1,6,{6;0;0;0;0;2})`

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: I'm aware of the alternative solutions around this specific case, but I'll require a solution using aggregate.

Comment: I'll be needing to use it later on to calculate a trend graph slope (1st polynom) using all values of a group and later on use this to calculate the deviation from each point (where the aggregate is actually used in) from the trend graph I just calculated. Since my dataset has over 80 groups later on, I'll be in need of it.
Excel 2013

Comment: There is an `AVERAGEIF`-function. Also I'm not sure, if you have to confirm your formula with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**.

Comment: If you are willing to use another non array formula try this: `= AVERAGEIF( [Group], [@Group], [Value] )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the aggregate function does not allow array arguments for SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT etc - it always returns #Value. You can only use array arguments with aggregate for things like Large, Small, StDev etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit vague what would be considered the "best", however you could consider adding all these amounts together (subtract the protein) would give you a matrix in which you can get the minimum.

Try:

=INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(MIN(INDEX(B2:B5+C2:C5+D2:D5-E2:E5+F2:F5,)),INDEX(B2:B5+C2:C5+D2:D5-E2:E5+F2:F5,),0))

Add a multiplication, e.g.: *1.05 to any of the columns if you consider them to be of more importance.

Comment: @JvdV Its this answer a copycat of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59821291/compare-products-use-multiple-properties
)?